# Why is it difficult to develop wide-bandwidth analog-to-digital converters?

Tags: adc, clock, signal-processing

How is bandwidth of analog-to-digital converters constrained? In particular, why would sample-and-hold subcircuitry not be able to perform high-speed switching?

Comment: Charge injection from the switch maybe?

Comment: There is also a problem with achieving a good impedance match at the input to an ADC, especially when you're trying to achieve more than a couple of hundred MHZ of Bandwidth

Answer (score 3):

all electronics have limits at the high-frequencies due to physical realities.  monolithic integrated circuits have a sorta problem that every internal device (every BJT, FET, MOSFET) is connected to a common substrate via a reversed-biased diode.  while reversed-biased diode junctions are normally understood to be *no connection*, there **is** a tiny amount of leakage.  in addition there are little walls of charge hanging out on both sides of the reversed-biased junction which are very similar to a charged capacitor.  so it's like a little femto-farad capacitor is connecting every node to a common substrate.  at sufficiently high frequencies, even that femto-farad capacitor will begin to conduct and to short circuit.